# Подскажите, как правильно написать фразу?

Tags: фразеология, согласование

Интервью «со стенда» компании или «на стенде» компании? Речь идёт об интервью с представителями компании, которые представили свою продукцию на своём отдельном стенде.

Comment: **...с представителями** компании, которые **представили**? **...свою** продукцию **на своём** стенде?

Comment: Да, написано некорректно. Но вопрос не об этой части. Это добавлено для понимания, что интервью было на стенде компании.